# ¿Cómo crear una matriz 2D con valores en 1D?

Tags: java, netbeans, bucle-for, matriz, 2d

Me explico, tengo 49 JTextField identificados de la siguiente manera:
*txt1, txt2, txt3... txt49*

Y a partir de los valores que contengan (números) quiero crear una matriz en 2D en la que pueda almacenarlos.

Es decir, si tengo 49 JTextField, mi matriz en 2D debe ser [6][6].

Estoy creando un `for` para recorrer las posiciones de la mariz y almacenar los valores de cada uno de los JTextField:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabla.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tabla.length; j++) {
                tabla[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText());
            }
        }
        save = true;
```

Y mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo dimensionar los JTextField con nombres planos, y almacenarlos en una matriz bidimensional?

Ejemplo de lo que me gustaría:

```
tabla[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(txt[numero del JTF (1, 2, 3... 49)].getText());
```

He intentado con

```
int cont = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tabla.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tabla.length; j++) {
                tabla[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(txt[cont].getText());
                cont++;
            }
        }
        save = true;
```

pero NetBeans me indica un error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes obtener el JTextField por su nombre de la siguiente forma:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test {

    private final JTextField txt1 = new JTextField();
    private final JTextField txt2 = new JTextField();

    public static void main(String... args) {

        Test t = new Test();

        t.txt1.setText("1");
        t.txt2.setText("2");

        int[][] tabla = new int[7][7];

        int contador = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < tabla.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tabla.length; j++) {

                try{
                    // obtener el campo con nombre txt + contador
                    Field f = t.getClass().getDeclaredField("txt" + contador++);
                    // convertir el campo a un JtextField
                    JTextField txt = (JTextField)f.get(t);
                    // agregar el valor a la tabla
                    tabla[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText());
                }catch (Exception ignored){}
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Sólamente tengo una pequeña duda. Me está guardando la matriz pero con posiciones distintas a las de las posiciones de los JTextField. Por ejemplo el txt25 con un valor de 2, estaría posicionado en tabla[4][4], pero me los guarda en tabla[0][4]. Y así con los demás valores.

Comment: Entonces el `txt1` debe estar en la posicion[0][0] el `txt2` en la posicion [0][1] y así?

Comment: Sí, así exactamente

Comment: No se estaba incrementado el contador, revisa de nuevo.

Comment: Ahora sí, te agradezco la ayuda. Igual le pasé solamente `this` en lugar de `t` ya que está dentro del ActionPerformed de un botón.

Answer (score 1):

Para guardar 49 valores en una matriz cuadrada, ésta debería ser de 7x7 no de 6x6. Igualmente podrías hacer tu código un poco más genérico para que no tengas que estar cambiando el tamaño de la matriz manualmente sino que sería mejor que lo calcule según la cantidad de `JTextField` que tengas:

```
int raiz = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(txt.length)); //Redondea la raíz cuadrada hacia arriba
int[][] tabla = new int[raiz][raiz];

for(int i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    tabla[i / raiz][i % raiz] = Integer.parseInt(txt[i].getText());
}
```

Con el código anterior basta con que sigas guardando `JTextField` en el arreglo `txt` y el código solito te crea una matriz que pueda contener todos los valores de los `JTextField`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, el detalle es que los JTextField no están almacenados en ningún arreglo, ya que necesitaba que cada uno de ellos tuviera eventos diferentes.

Comment: @OscarAnibal Pensé que los tenías en un arreglo porque extraes el texto de esta manera: `txt[cont].getText()`. Igualmente los puedes poner dentro de un arreglo y aún así asignarles eventos individualmente.

Comment: Es que lo que necesito es una manera de añadir ese número dinámicamente al for con algún método. El nómbre de la variable txt pero con algo que pueda añadirle el número. Tipo: txt+[cont]